# How do I ensure that my customer does not misuse my solution offered via Google Cloud Marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am planning to deploy a vm solution on Google Cloud Marketplace. I have two concerns about this.

1. I have read [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) document and it mentions that google cloud images can be exported to cloud storage. Can this method be used to run the image in a local environment.
2. The VM solution I am providing contains an application binary. If customer copies this binary on some other machine, he will be able to run it. How do I prevent that from happening.

Forgive me if my questions are absurd. I am not able to find answers to these questions anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The method described in your provided link states that Cloud Storage is it’s only possible destination. I have looked into it and so far I haven’t found another way through the console to do this. I have as well looked into the gcloud command to see if it could once again come to the rescue - so far no luck.  Though I am not sure if this would suit your needs you can download objects from buckets in Cloud Storage. So in a way you can get the image (if it’s an object) downloaded to your local environment.

As for your second question , about preventing someone from copying your application binary, what you are asking is copy protection. This is where I quote something from the GCP console itself :

Cloud Storage IDs
Project members can access Cloud Storage data according to their project roles. To modify other permissions, use these group IDs to identify these roles.

Which may or may not suit your needs ( as it pertains to Cloud Storage on not on-premises).

Comment: Is there a way to check if my binary is running inside a virtual machine spawned using a licensed image.